# Are there any problems that are easier to implement on a turing machine than a conventional computer?

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines, automata-theory

I know for example finding integers where their modulus n is k maps nicely to finite state machines and push down automata's work well for parsing deterministic grammars. I was wondering if there are any problems that are like that for turing machines.

Comment: I think this question is rather belong to https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [tia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/397807/tia), these kinds of questions are better for [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). I would say that the question is not well stated, since conventional computers are basically a type of Turing machine. It depends on what kind of Turing machine you are working with. For example, many problems can be solved much faster on a non-deterministic Turing machine than on a classical computer (which is deterministic).

Comment: Well think it can be inferred I mean the standard definition, but yeah cs is probably a better place for it. I'm new to posting here so thanks for the guidance.